# jQuery - trying to get data-name value ( string )

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
  <ul>
    <li id="bapf_2_287_label">
      <input data-name="curry" id="bapf_2_287" type="checkbox" value="287" style="display:none;">
      <label for="bapf_2_287" aria-label="curry" class="awa" style="background-image: url("https://website/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/undefined.jpg");">
        <span class="bapf_img_span h2em w2em" style="background: url(https://website/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/curry.jpg) no-repeat scroll 50% 50% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);background-size: cover;">
          <span class="bapf_clr_span_abslt"></span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li id="bapf_2_286_label">
      <input data-name="darkgrey" id="bapf_2_286" type="checkbox" value="286" style="display:none;">
      <label for="bapf_2_286" aria-label="darkgrey" class="awa" style="background-image: url("https://website/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/undefined.jpg");">
        <span class="bapf_img_span h2em w2em" style="background: url() no-repeat scroll 50% 50% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);background-size: cover;">
          <span class="bapf_clr_span_abslt"></span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
           var getCol = jQuery("input").data('data-name');
           var imageUrl = "https://website/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/" + getCol + ".jpg";
          jQuery(".bapf_sfilter .bapf_img_span").css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
```

I am trying to add the value of the `data-name` to the URL to display a swatch image. It keeps showing the URL but with `'undefined'` at the end.

This will need to be a loop, but I wish to get the functionality of it working first. There will be many colour image swatches.

Comment: Could you share some of html to see how `data-name` is passed

Comment: @MichaelShopsin i've edited the question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var getCol = jQuery("input").data('data-name');`

should be:

`var getCol = jQuery("input").data('name');`

when you specify it in html it will be `data-name="something"`

ex:
`<div id="dataTag" data-name="something">`

but when you use the jQuery method to read a data attribute you need to specify just the name

`$('#dataTag').data('name')`

```js
$(function(){
  $('ul > li').each(function() {
     var getCol = $('input', $(this)).data('name');
     var imageUrl = "https://website/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/" + getCol + ".jpg";
    $(".bapf_img_span", $(this)).css('background-image', 'url("' + imageUrl + '")');
    console.log('CSS background-image =', $(".bapf_img_span", $(this)).css('background-image'));  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="bapf_2_287_label">
      <input data-name="curry" id="bapf_2_287" type="checkbox" value="287" style="display:none;">
      <label for="bapf_2_287" aria-label="curry" class="awa" style="background-image: url("https://website/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/undefined.jpg");">
        <span class="bapf_img_span h2em w2em" style="background: url(https://website/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/curry.jpg) no-repeat scroll 50% 50% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);background-size: cover;">
          <span class="bapf_clr_span_abslt"></span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li id="bapf_2_286_label">
      <input data-name="darkgrey" id="bapf_2_286" type="checkbox" value="286" style="display:none;">
      <label for="bapf_2_286" aria-label="darkgrey" class="awa" style="background-image: url("https://website/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/undefined.jpg");">
        <span class="bapf_img_span h2em w2em" style="background: url() no-repeat scroll 50% 50% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);background-size: cover;">
          <span class="bapf_clr_span_abslt"></span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I think  i know what you mean but i want it to find the name for each colour ( it will be a loop ) so i want it to find the value of data-name each time as it will be different

Comment: That's pretty easy, you just need to cycle  all elements you need to change ... all <li>'s probably?

Comment: Just tried the data('name') and it still came back undefined.

Comment: You need to specify correctly the element holding the data ... ok, I'll do it for you, just give me a few minutes.

Comment: thank you, i specified it properly & it worked. I need to now loop it. thank you so much

Comment: I have edited my answer with an example loop to change CSS `background-image` of all `li` entries. Check it.

Comment: thank you so much i've accepted your answer have a great day :)

Comment: Have a great day mate!

Comment: Hi, I have noticed another issue with my jQuery. Unfortunately, when the 'Apply Filters' or even 'reset filters', ajax call is clicked, the colour images that i set in the code above disappears. Do you know any way of finding a plugins ajax call, and then if the jQuery can be edited again to prevent the styling from disappearing?